# Compare 2 css style - Property and Value Equality

Tags: css

How to compare the equality of 2 css styles like:

`color: red`

```
color:rgb(255,0,0)



color: #f00
```

I want to compare any css selector and any property value - if they are given - how can i know if 2 css rules containing a single property mean the same thing??

Comment: please read tag description before using

Comment: You can’t do that within CSS. You’d need a programming language for that kind of comparison. What’s your use case?

Answer (score 0):

Unsure what you are trying to achieve here, but maybe look at a CSS comparison tool like [CSS Compare](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=csscompare).

This tool will allow you to compare two CSS files and output unique styles. It works by evaluating individual CSS styles, so you might be able to see where the colour *red* is used, even if it's sometimes written as `rgb(255,0,0)` or as `#f00` in other place.